# How to iterate through dict values containing lists and remove items?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Python novice here. I have a dictionary of lists, like so:

```
d = {
  1: ['foo', 'foo(1)', 'bar', 'bar(1)'],
  2: ['foobaz', 'foobaz(1)', 'apple', 'apple(1)'],
  3: ['oz', 'oz(1)', 'boo', 'boo(1)']
}
```

I am trying to figure out how to loop through the keys of the dictionary and the corresponding list values and remove all strings in each in list with a parantheses tail. So far this is what I have:

```
for key in keys:
    for word in d[key]...: # what else needs to go here?
        regex = re.compile('\w+\([0-9]\)')
        re.sub(regex, '', word)  # Should this be a ".pop()" from list instead?
```

I would like to do this with a list comprehension, but as I said, I can't find much information on looping through dict keys and corresponding dict value of lists. What's the most efficient way of setting this up?

Comment: The problems you'll run into with this aren't peculiar to lists that happen to be dict values. You should get helpful information by searching for things like 'modifying a list while iterating over it'. eumiro's answer about creating a new dictionary with the modifications instead of modifying the existing values in-place neatly end-runs these issues, however.

Comment: The items of your lists, are they strings? Or some object?

Comment: @Eric They're strings. Thanks for pointing that out — example edited.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can re-build the dictionary, letting only elements without parenthesis through:

```
d = {k:[elem for elem in v if not elem.endswith(')')] for k,v in d.iteritems()}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
temp_dict = d
for key, value is temp_dict:
    for elem in value:
        if temp_dict[key][elem].find(")")!=-1:
            d[key].remove[elem]
```

you can't edit a list while iterating over it, so you create a copy of your list as temp_list and if you find parenthesis tail in it, you delete corresponding element from your original list.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can do it without rebuilding the dictionary, which may be preferable if it's huge...

```
for k, v in d.iteritems():
   d[k] = filter(lambda x: not x.endswith(')'), v)
```